# Reuse a widget using g_object_ref()

Tags: c++, c, widget, gtk

I have a GtkGrid and I want to show inside one cell a widget or another according to the choices of the user. I wrote my code according to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove), which says:

> Removes widget from container . widget must be inside container . **Note**
>   **that container will own a reference to widget , and that this may be**
>   **the last reference held; so removing a widget from its container can**
>   **destroy that widget. If you want to use widget again, you need to add**
>   **a reference to it while it’s not inside a container, using**
>   **g_object_ref()**. If you don’t want to use widget again it’s usually
>   more efficient to simply destroy it directly using
>   gtk_widget_destroy() since this will remove it from the container and
>   help break any circular reference count cycles.

Here is some fragment of the code:

```
// Definitions
GtkWidget *myList1, *myList2;

// Creation
myList1 = gtk_tree_view_new();
myList2 = gtk_tree_view_new();
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(gridList), myList1, 0, 1, 2, 1); // Attach myList1

// Switching in runtime
if (x) {
    g_object_ref(myList1);
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(gridList), myList1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(gridList), myList2, 0, 1, 2, 1);
} else {
    g_object_ref(myList2);
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(gridList), myList2);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(gridList), myList1, 0, 1, 2, 1);   
}
```

When I perform the switching (I want to remove `myList1` and insert `myList2`), then I get an empty cell in my grid. Anyway, when I repeat the switching, the object `myList1` reappears in the grid as I want.

I don't get any GTK warning on the terminal during those operations. `x` is set `true` or `false` correctly according to the selection of two radio buttons.

What's going on? Am I missing some passages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `gtk_widget_show_all(myList2)` for that to show up. Your `gtk_widget_show_all()` that shows the GtkWindow the GtkGrid is a child of only shows the children *at the time of the call*.

Your code has a latent bug: the reference counts will always increment by two but decrement by one because `gtk_grid_attach()` (actually `gtk_widget_set_parent()`) does its own `g_object_ref()` (actually `g_object_ref_sink()`).